# Issues with ASP and XSL Encoding

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic

I am parsing my XML and XSL through classic ASP. (That is just what the server can run) My XML and XSL files are encoded to UTF-8 but when parsing, they turn to UTF-16. This is causing my French chars to be incorrectly represented.

ASP code:

```
'Load XML
Set URL_xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0")
URL_xml.async = false
URL_xml.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
URL_xml.preserveWhiteSpace = True
URL_xml.load(Server.MapPath("xml/1_branches.xml"))
'Load XSL
Dim URL_xsl : Set URL_xsl = CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0")
URL_xsl.async = false
URL_xsl.load(Server.MapPath("xsl/default.xsl"))

Dim xslTemplate : Set xslTemplate = CreateObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate.3.0")
xslTemplate.stylesheet = URL_xsl

Dim processor : Set processor = xslTemplate.createProcessor()
processor.addParameter "auth", cookie_auth
processor.addParameter "user_name", cookie_user_name
processor.input = URL_xml
processor.transform()

strTrans = processor.output
strFolder = strFolder & strFolders & strTrans
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <branches>
    <branch>Audit and Evaluation</branch>
    <folder>ae-ve</folder>
    <program></program>
    <section>About EC</section>
  </branches>
</root>
```

XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html" indent="yes" ></xsl:output>
    <xsl:param name="auth"/>
    <xsl:param name="user_name"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="$auth = 'Super'">
            <p>There are <xsl:value-of select="count(root/branches)"/> individual folders.</p>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/branches">
                <xsl:variable name="folder" select="folder" />
                <fieldset><legend><strong><a href="url_list.asp?fldr={$folder}.xml"><xsl:value-of select="folder"/></a></strong></legend><!--h3 class="folder"><a href="url_list.asp?fldr={$folder}.xml"><xsl:value-of select="folder"/></a></h3-->
                <p class='details'><strong>Com Advisor: </strong>
                <xsl:for-each select="./people/person[@resp = 'com']">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>, 
                </xsl:for-each><br />
                <strong>Branch: </strong><xsl:value-of select="branch"/><br />
                <strong>Folder: </strong><xsl:value-of select="folder"/><br />
                <strong>Program: </strong><xsl:value-of select="program"/><br />
                <strong>Section: </strong><xsl:value-of select="section"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have been fighting with this for a bit now. I have found some good advice here, but most of the solutions lead to saving the file through a stream. I need to have the output from the XSl as a string variable for further use in the document.

Comment: Your not showing it, but has your asp page been set to UTF-8 too? e.g. like this _<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>_

Comment: No, but I will try that right now. Thank you.

Comment: AardVark71 You are a genius. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. Since it was useful I'll post it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure your processing page is in UTF-8 (and you are not working with webservers default codepage) you can set the codepage as follows for your page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
```

or

```
<%
Response.CodePage = 65001
%>
```

Optionally: If you want to output those characters to browser (which doesn't seem the case here), you can set the output encoding also as follows:

```
<%
Response.Charset= "utf-8"
%>
```